# Cannot use the special principal 'dbo' when addressing SQLMI risk VA2108

Tags: permissions, role, azure-sql-managed-instance

We've just set up a new SQL Managed Instance on Azure, and have restored a database to it for testing.  After running an initial Azure Vulnerability Assessment, the results include this:

> VA2108 - Minimal set of principals should be members of fixed high
> impact database roles
>
> Fixed database roles may have administrative
> permissions on the system. Following the principle of least privilege,
> it is important to minimize membership in fixed database roles and
> keep a baseline of these memberships.
>
> Remediation - Remove members who should not have access to the database role
>
> ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [dbo]

I don't want to ignore this if its a real concern, but am worried about inadvertantly damaging something due to a lack of experience.  There are many web sites [showing how to 'fix' the error](https://jasonbrimhall.info/2018/11/07/cannot-use-the-special-principal-back-to-basics/), but each is based on its own scenario.

Within SQLMI we have the following logins:

1. SqlMiAdmin (the Azure-created user account that owns the instance)
2. DbUser1 - See below

Within the database itself we have the following users:

1. DbUser1 - Mapped to the above login for CRUD operations via stored procedures only
2. dbo - not used (directly, AFAIK)

The owner of the database (in Properties) is shown as `SqlMiAdmin`.  Any schema changes and database updates are performed by me using `SqlMiAdmin`.

I'm unsure about how to tackle VA2108 and it's implications in doing so.  If the `dbo` user isn't used in the database then I figured I'd try following the Azure recommendation, but it fails:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [dbo] 
-- Cannot use the special principal 'dbo'.
```

Can anyone please recommend an appropriate course of action?